# Как округлять числа с шагом 0.25?

Tags: python, python-3.x, округление

Есть у меня список флоатов:

```
['14.42', '15.22', '16.10', '13.99', '15.55', '14.20', '15.03', '16.29']
```

нужно сделать округление к ближайшему, но не целому числу, а дробному, с нашом на .0, .25, .50, .75, 1.0 например:

- если 14.42 - ему ближе 14.50
- или 14.20 - ему ближе 14.25
- или 14.10 - ему ближе 14.00
- или 15.90 - ему ближе 16.00

Comment: Список флоатов или строк?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я получаю ввиде стр

Comment: Умножаем на 4, округляем, делим на 4. Профит

Comment: @AlexeyTen :)) звучит круто, но не понял

Comment: @AlexeyTen не получилось, a = 14.40 
a = a * 4 
a = int(a) 
a = a / 4, Ответ должен быть 4.50 потому что он ближе к .50

Comment: @django_starter round(x*4)/4

Comment: Так надо округлять, а не отсекать дробную часть.

Comment: @mkkik все получилось, спасибо

Comment: @AlexeyTen все получилось, спасибо

Comment: @Jack_oS все получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно написать универсальную функцию:

```
def round_custom(num, step):
    return round(num / step) * step
```

с параметром под изменяющийся шаг округления:

```
>>> print(round_custom(15.93, 0.25))
16.0

>>> print(round_custom(15.93, 0.5))
16.0

>>> print(round_custom(15.93, 0.1))
15.9

>>> print(round_custom(15.93, 1))
16

>>> print(round_custom(15.93, 10))
20
```

Для вашего примера:

```
>>> data = ['14.42', '15.22', '16.10', '13.99', '15.55', '14.20', '15.03', '16.29']
>>> step = 0.25  # степень округления, 1/4 в данном случае
>>> round_data = [round_custom(float(x), step) for x in data]
```

тогда в `round_data`:

```
>>> round_data
[14.5, 15.25, 16.0, 14.0, 15.5, 14.25, 15.0, 16.25]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a=[14.42,14.20, 14.10, 15.90]
>>> [round(i*4)/4 for i in a]
[14.5, 14.25, 14.0, 16.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю функциональный вариант (без циклов), хотя по сути тоже самое, конечно, но чуть в другой форме:

```
a = ['14.42', '15.22', '16.10', '13.99', '15.55', '14.20', '15.03', '16.29']
print(list(map(lambda x: round(x * 4) / 4, map(float, a))))
```